# problems importing text in python

Tags: python, string, file, text

With python, I'm trying to take a text file, and then create one long list of words (with words in the order they appear in the document).

What I have so far goes through each line and then just basically adds the words to the long list.

It is supposed to lowercase each word, and remove any punctuation it finds.

```
wordstory=[a.lower().strip(string.punctuation) for b in [line.split() for line in open('alice.txt')] for a in b]
```

It seems that some punctuation isn't recognized by .strip(string.punctuation) for removal, and further, in some cases, the punctuation gets converted to odd codes.

I end up with situations like this with `\xe2\x80\x94` not supposed to be there at all.

```
..
 'she',
 'spoke\xe2\x80\x94fancy',
 'curtseying',
..
```

Also, when an apostrophe occurs next to a double quotation, the apostrophe isn't removed by `.strip(string.punctuation)`. I end up with:

```
..
'she',
 "couldn't",
 'answer',
..
```

Can someone provide some code that will help, and or point me to a resource that will help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Can you provide a sample text file and the code that you have tried so far?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to read a unicode file?

Comment: I bet you have multibyte unicode punctuation characters in your source document.

Comment: note that `str.strip` only removes characters from the beginning and end of strings, thus `parents'` becomes `parents` but `parent's` doesn't change at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're having unicode problems, as well as being unnecessarily obfuscated with the list comprehension.

I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import string

file = open("""text_file.txt""", "r")
raw_text = file.read()

# stripping punctuation
punctuation = set(string.punctuation)
trimmed_text = ''.join(char for char in raw_text if char not in punctuation)

# splitting into list
word_list = trimmed_text.split(" ")

# removing duplicates
unique_word_list = set(word_list)

# or if you're preserving the order, maybe try:
unique_word_list = []
for word in word_list:
    if word not in unique_word_list:
        unique_word_list.append(word)

print(unique_word_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all punctuation use `translate`and `string.maketrans`:

```
In [94]: import string

In [95]: a ="she's all foo!"

In [96]: a.lower().translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
Out[96]: 'shes all foo'
```

`str.strip` only removes chars from the end or start of a string.

Comment: It seems that there was a strange dash character in the original text file that was becoming \xe2\x80\x94 when it was imported into python - why is this? Thanks for telling me about the translate function but it didn't get rid of the apostrophe for the rare situations in which it occurred right beside a double quote as I described.